# Docker user executing a process cannot be removed

Tags: ps, docker, resources

I have some resources used by a specific user that I had to delete because it was taking a lot of resources from the server. When I listed the processes in the server the deleted user now shows as “1001” instead of the name it used to show before I deleted it.

```
%Cpu(s): 19.8 us, 29.5 sy,  0.0 ni, 50.7 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.1 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem :  3882456 total,   183568 free,  2003808 used,  1695080 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  1679356 total,  1155300 free,   524056 used.  1463480 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
9192 1001      20   0 2068436  74700  10284 S   0.3  1.9   3:02.86 node
```

By using `systemctl status` I found the process and the docker container ID that the user is executing is in:

```
       ├─docker
       │ ├─42b40e73687acb7fcd9a0e43372ced7588b5568c942f740d06510ab0e85b1462
       │ │ ├─17156 /bin/sh -e /usr/local/sbin/start.sh
           └─11148 node --debug --nolazy dist-release/server
```

So, I went into the container and I look to the start.sh file but it’s just an executable file, there’s no indication inside of the file that the user is getting called inside of the executable file.

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                    COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                                                                   NAMES
    apiassets_1
42b40e73687a        local.io/api-statements:development     "start.sh"               21 hours ago        Up 18 hours         0.0.0.0:32785->3000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5966->5858/tcp
```

What I want to do is stopping this user to use this resources, so I was just curious how can I either find how this user is calling this script to stop it or how can I stop it.

Comment: Kill all running process with `docker kill $(docker ps -q)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for anybody following with my issue. It was a little odd what was happening but the user it was running that process happened to have the same ID inside of the docker container as the host, so when I listed all the processes the user ID of the user inside of the container was getting mapped to a specific user I had in the host. 
Which explains why when I deleted the user in the host I was still seeing that the process was running as "1001".

So, now I'm clear that this is how it should be working.

I also looked at this tool called [csysdig](http://www.sysdig.org/) in case anyone is interested, which seems like it would solve a problem like the one I had since it would give you specific information about each container. In my case I was seeing processes happening in the host as well as the containers so it was really hard to really inspect what was happening.